# How to add amd module(requirejs) as grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs helpers

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-requirejs

I want to add a javascript file(which is a requirejs amd module) in "helpers" in grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs configuration. Im getting Uncaught Error: mismatch: Mismatched anonymous define() module. How to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
jasmine:  {
            test: {
                src: ['app/scripts/**/*.js' ],
                options: {
                    specs: 'spec/*.js',
                    helpers: ['xyz.js', 'util.js'],

                    template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
                    templateOptions: {
                        requireConfig: {
                            baseUrl: "app/scripts/",
                            requireConfigFile: 'require-config.js'                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Add the current snippet if possible, will help to debug/understand better